# Keep Qtip in page bounds?

Tags: javascript

I am using QTip for the sidebar:
[image]

As you can see, the the QTip goes slightly offscreen and creates an ugly hscrollbar on my screen.

Here is the code:

```
function appendCalendarEventToList(className, event) {

    var eventObject = {
        title: event.title,
        id: event.id,
        type: event.type,
        color: event.color,
        description: event.description,
        canReoccur: event.canReoccur,
        reoccurVal: event.reoccurVal,
        estHours: event.estHours
    };

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = 'external-event';
    div.style.background = event.color;
    div.innerHTML = event.title;

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(div).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    $(div).draggable({
        helper: function () {
            $copy = $(this).clone();
            $copy.data('eventObject', eventObject);
            $copy.css({ "list-style": "none", "width": $(this).outerWidth() }); return $copy;
        },
        appendTo: 'body',
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

    $(className).append(div);

   $(div).qtip({
        content: event.title,

        position:
            {
                target: 'mouse'
            },
        //  show: { event: 'click' },
        hide: { event: 'mousedown mouseleave' },
        style: {
            width: 200,
            padding: 5,
            color: 'black',
            textAlign: 'left',
            border: {
                width: 1,
                radius: 3
            },


            classes: {
                tooltip: 'ui-widget',
                tip: 'ui-widget',
                title: 'ui-widget-header',
                content: 'ui-widget-content'
            }
        }
    });


    return div;
}
```

Now, what I would love is, if I could keep it inside the page (if(tip.right > page.right, tip.right = page.right)) or something..

Is there some way to do this?

At the least, I would like to ensure that it never causes an hscroll bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three silly answers...

1. use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute` on the qtip.
2. use `max-width` instead of `width` and define `right:0`, that way the right side of the qtip will never exceed the rightmost side of the body.
3. try [tipy](http://www.xpy.gr/tipy) a jQuery tooltip plugin I made myself, (in that case tell me what you think).